# How to call JSON methods from C# WebService from external server

Tags: c#, javascript, json, web-services, cross-domain

How could I use an asp.net web service(in c#) in a HTML5/JavaScript site?
AND the web service is not in the same site as the client, so it would be a cross-domain request.

Comment: This isn't a question

Comment: No it's not, but its an answer that can solve the "how to" question of it, I checked on StackOverflow FAQ and they encourage to post questions with answers, so if this can help at least 1 guy, My job will be done.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but this isn't a question and an answer.  It's the briefest description of a problem and an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little experience in web programming, and while moving all my asp.net page to HTML5 and JS for a faster interface I have a real struggle trying to connect my webservice to js, JSON was the answer, and the information received dropped from 2Kb to 128 bytes, so on mobile devices its somehow useful

**first / server side**

***mywebservice.asmx***

The next web service will be hosted in the site, Site.com

### then the address would be "Site.com/MYWS.asmx/JSONMethod"

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://...")]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MYWS
{
    [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string JSONMethod(/*ParType ParName, ParType ParName2,.. etc*/)
        {
                List<object> tempobjects = new List<object>();
                tempobjects.Add(new { ID = id, Val = val /*more params=> ParName= "ParValue", etc..*/ });

                var retVal = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(tempobjects.ToArray());

                Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var p = "";
                if (Context.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("callback") == true)
                    p = Context.Request.Params["callback"].ToString();
        Context.Response.Write(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}({1})", p, retVal));
        }
}
```

**second / client side**

***myJS.js***

```
function MyJSMethod(){
$.ajax({
    url: "Site.com/MYWS.asmx/JSONMethod",
    data:{ParName: "parValue"/*, ParName2... etc*/},
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"jsonp" //if the method
    })
    .done(
        function(data){
            //Do what you need with the json data retrieved
            //... CODE HERE ...

            //In case you need to call a method from another js being used
            //window["JSmethod"](data)//if the json received is needed
        }
    ).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
    alert(jqXHR);
    alert(textStatus);
    alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Hope this works for you as this works for me.
Good luck and happy coding.

-Poncho